# Jquery selector <td/>

Tags: jquery

-I'm learning Jquery. i dont understand this `$('<td/>')` selector  in this code :

```
$('<td/>').insertAfter($(this)).text(height).css('border', 'thin solid red');
```

-Can any one show me what is it?

Comment: `build a td element insert it after this give it a text that's equal to the variable height and apply a thin solid red border`.

Comment: Could I suggest visiting the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/)? Specifically the pages for [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/), [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), and [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)? Also, to read about a jQuery method simply go to the URL of the form: `http://api.jquery.com/ + methodName/`, so: `http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/`.

Comment: I just dont understand what is <td/>?

Comment: In that case you need to look at this page, explaining [`jQuery()`/ $()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

Answer (score 3):

`$('<td/>')` creates an DOM element with tag `td`.

`insertAfter($(this))` appends the element after `this` element.

`.text(height)` changes the text within the `td` tags.

Finally, `.css('border', 'thin solid red');` applies a red border to the `td` element.

Answer (score 0):

`$('<td/>')` creates a new blank `<td>` element and wraps it in the jQuery object.

It would be the same, as if you created the element in pure javascript and then selected it with `$('.selector')`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down into its components, and maybe that will be more instructive:

```
$('<td/>') // this is initializing a new DOM Node. At this point, however, it's not actually connected to anything, it's just a DOM Node hanging out in the DOM and not attached to the document flow.

.insertAfter($(this)) // now, this is telling jQuery to take that TD element you just created, and insert it after whatever $(this) evaluates to... assuming this is inside, say, a click handler, it would evaluate to the object that triggered the click event, and attach the TD element after "this" element.

.text(height) // says, "set the .text of your TD element to whatever is in the height variable" ... you're basically plugging text inside your TD element.

.css('border', 'thin solid red') // is telling jQuery to modify the TD's style, adding a style for border that is thin, solid and red.
```

See an example I threw together on jsFiddle for an example of how this would work.
http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/xLJHx/

(an interesting follow-up question should present itself if you try to play around with the jsFiddle I linked you to, but I don't want to muddy the waters here)